# SenML parser for C# .net

Tags: c#, .net-core, iot, cbor

I am looking for a viable solution to parse SenML data into JSON using C#.NET.

Preferably the following types -

- application/senml+json
- application/senml+cbor

I have seen packages in Python namely - **senml** & **cbor** which are used to read and parse the SenML data to JSON arrays but looking for a similar and stable C# alternative.

Any help will me much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/SenML.NET

Comment: Thanks @RobertHarvey for your response. I had come across this but could not find proper documentation or usage references. Please let me know if I am missing something or if you have used it previously. Thanks !